# Why am I getting this JS error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, autocomplete

I get this JS error:

```
jquery-1.5.1.min.js:16Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined
d.d.extend._Deferred.f.resolveWithjquery-1.5.1.min.js:16
d.d.extend.readyjquery-1.5.1.min.js:16
d.c.addEventListener.A
```

and it's from this code for the jquery UI autocomplete plugin in my application.js file:

```
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
         return $( "<li></li>" )
           .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
           .append( "<a>" + item.topic.name + "</a>" )
           .appendTo( ul );
            };
```

I get this code whenever I load a page that does NOT have the text field that the autocomplete code is acting on. Why and how can I get rid of this error?

I'd like to note that although I am getting this error, my application is working normally. Should I even be worrying about this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(...).data('autocomplete')
```

is undefined, and you can't set a property of undefined.  try:

```
var obj = $(...).data('autocomplete');
obj && (obj._renderItem = function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: @Blender, because the jQuery selector is returning an empty array.  that empty array does not have a .data() function, so the .data function is returning undefined, and you can't set a property of undefined, as cwolves has explained.

Comment: As the initial question says: "I get this code whenever I load a page that does NOT have the text field that the autocomplete code is acting on" -- thus `$(...)` is an empty jQuery set and `$(...).data('anything')` == `undefined`

Comment: @nathan -- not quite.  Empty jQuery sets still have a `.data()` function, it'll just always return undefined

Comment: Well, that's explained by the error. But I get what you mean.

Comment: @cwolves I get this error from your code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: @cwolves, learn something new every day.  thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Justin - Whoops, sorry about that.  You need parens around the assignment, I updated my code.

Answer (score 9):

this problem appeared to me when i upgrade the jquery ui from old one to 1.10.0

just change

```
$('.foo').data("autocomplete")._render...;
```

To

```
$('.foo').data("uiAutocomplete")._render...;
```

source
[JQueryUI 1.10.0 Autocompleter renderItem problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461787/jqueryui-1-10-0-autocompleter-renderitem-problems)

Answer (score 4):

why not just wrap the autocomplete code in a check to see if that element exists?

something like this:

```
if ($'#myElementId').length) {
    $('#myElementId').data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
         return $( "<li></li>" )
           .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
           .append( "<a>" + item.topic.name + "</a>" )
           .appendTo( ul );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `.data("autocomplete")` isn't returning an object, as the error says:

> Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined

If you are doing this:

```
$('.foo').data("autocomplete")._render...;
```

You try breaking it up:

```
$('.foo').data("autocomplete");
$('.foo')._renderItem = ...;
```

I've never encountered `_renderItem`, so I'll look more in to that.

---

Actually, this question seems to explain a problem really similar to your's: [Using _renderItem kind of breaks autocomplete field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086952/using-renderitem-kind-of-breaks-autocomplete-field)

Comment: _renderItem is part of autocomplete, and he can't break it up because it's setting _renderItem on the result of `$('.foo').data('autocomplete')`, not on `$('.foo')`

Comment: Ahh, good point. You probably know what you're talking about, as I don't tend to use jQuery plugins; it's heavy by itself.