# How to set-up jQuery-UI 1.10 autocomplete custom display

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My jquery-UI autocompletes are broken when I switch from jquery-ui 1.9 to 1.10 (with jquery 1.8.3 in both cases).

The [upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#autocomplete) indicates that the `item.autocomplete` syntax is replaced by `ui-autocomplete-item` but I cannot get it to work. In fact I think the example for [Custom data and display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) is broken as the `desc` is not displayed in the dropdown.

This may be very simple but I am blocked, an example would be very much appreciated, in particular one that would display HTML (like `<strong>`) correctly in the dropdown.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513251/cannot-set-property-renderitem-of-undefined-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-html/14443936#14443936

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much, I wish I could give your the rep... If you answer (instead of comment) I'll + you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

btr basically gave me the answer but for others here is what I had not understood:

As per the [upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#autocomplete) I had changed `item.autocomplete` to `ui-autocomplete-item` but I forgot to change `autocomplete` to `ui-autocomplete`.
So my (**invalid**) code looked like this (last part of my autocomplete call):

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return jQuery( "<li>" ).data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item ).append( "<a>--" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );
```

Note that I changed `item.autocomplete` to `ui-autocomplete-item` on line 2 but that I forgot to change `autocomplete` to `ui-autocomplete` on line 1

The equivalent working code is:

```
.data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return jQuery('<li>').data('ui-autocomplete-item', item ).append('<a>--'+ item.label+'<br>'+item.desc+'</a>').appendTo(ul);
    };
```

Thanks again for the help btr!