# Jquery Ui AutoComplee select ui.item is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete on my page that fetches and displays the data correctly.
data : `Object { custId="CUST2", invoiceNo="B1"}`
jquery v1.8.2 min
jQuery UI - v1.10.3

```
$("#invoiceNo").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            if($.trim($(this.element).val())==""){
               return;
            }
            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
                var self = this;
                ul.append("<li><table width='100%' class='table table-condensed table-bordered' style='margin-bottom:0px;'><tr><td width='20%'><b>Invoice No</b></td><td width='20%'><b>Customer ID</b></td></tr></table></li>");
                $.each(items, function(index, item) {
                    self._renderItem(ul, item);
                });
            };
            $.getJSON("getInvoiceList.html", {
               query : $.trim($(this.element).val()),
                type:"del",
            }, response).error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            }); 
        },
        open: function() { 
            // After menu has been opened, set width
            $('.ui-menu').width(700);
        },
        minLength : 1,
        select : function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item);
            $("#invoiceNo").val(ui.item.invoiceNo);
            //setCustomerDetails(ui.item.number);

            getInvoiceDetailForReturn(ui.item.invoiceNo);
            return false;
        },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $.jGrowl(xhr.responseText); 
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {               
         return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete-item", item) .append("<a><table width='100%' class='table table-condensed table-hover' style='margin-bottom:0px;'><tr><td width='20%'>" + item.invoiceNo + "</td><td width='20%'>"+item.custId+"</td></tr></table></a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
```

first i have error `$(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is undefined`
it solve that Problem

turns out I had to change

```
data("Autocomplete" )._renderItemData = function( ul, item ) {
```

and

```
.data( "item.autocomplete", item )
```

to

```
 data("ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
```

and

```
.data( "item.autocomplete-item", item )
```

so it doesn't get the ui.item object...

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Sébastien ui.item is undefined

Comment: @Sébastien alert in Select is undefined

Comment: Hello @Sébastien Bro When I am use jquery-ui-1.9.2 autocomplete work properly.
But if i am open dialog  make two ui-widget-overlay div after close dialog one ui-widget-overlay div remove but one is  remaining.Means My Problem is that if my dialog property Modal is True then after close dialog can not remove modal property false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had this problem myself when [switching to jQuery-UI 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442471/how-to-set-up-jquery-ui-1-10-autocomplete-custom-display). You must replace `item.autocomplete-item` with `ui-autocomplete-item`.

So taking only the last 3 lines of your code block this becomes:

```
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {               
  return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item) .append("<a><table width='100%' class='table table-condensed table-hover' style='margin-bottom:0px;'><tr><td width='20%'>" + item.invoiceNo + "</td><td width='20%'>"+item.custId+"</td></tr></table></a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

Here again is the link to the [upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#autocomplete).

Comment: In My Page add ui-autocomplete in only one auto complete so it not working now fantanstic working Thank you @Sebastien