# Conflicting Jquery scripts stop page from loading - Console.log Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work with a Web-To-Print back-end service that handles my websites inventory and pricing from another server. I'm re-designing their site on the front-end. I created a Auto complete script for a search bar i'm adding to the site, but after linking the script the site idles out while loading. It seems my Jquery.autocomplete.js file is conflicting with their Jquery.combobox.js.

[image: Screen Shot of Console.Log Error]

I'm new to JavaScript, and i'm still taking a course. Does anybody know if there is a way to fix this without having to change their script? Is there something i can change on my end to fix this error?

## Jquery.autocomplete.js - Script I'm Uploading to Their Server

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stinkytofu/mkuv2ska/)

## Jquery.combobox.js - Script On Their Server (Conflicting Script Line 66)

[Conflicting Script Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stinkytofu/90jjskux/)

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/stinkytofu/90jjskux/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: It might have to do something to do with jquery-ui version you are using. Look into this thred for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513251/cannot-set-property-renderitem-of-undefined-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-html

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the smallest program necessary to reproduce the issue. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)