# JQuery: why am I getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, dreamfactory

This code is supposed to take an ISBN or name of a book and run it against googles book API, returning valid results. The code appears to work on its own, but when we put it into our Dreamfactory server, it returns that it cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 $(function() {
 $("#txtBookSearch").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var booksUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?printType=books&maxResults=20&q=" + encodeURIComponent(request.term);
    $.ajax({
      url: booksUrl,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data.items, function(item) {
          if (item.volumeInfo.authors && item.volumeInfo.title && item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers && item.volumeInfo.publishedDate) {
            return {
              // label value will be shown in the suggestions
              ebook: (item.saleInfo.isEbook == null ? "" : item.saleInfo.isEbook),
              title: item.volumeInfo.title,
              id: item.id,
              author: item.volumeInfo.authors[0],
              authors: item.volumeInfo.authors,
              isbn: item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers,
              publishedDate: item.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
              image: (item.volumeInfo.imageLinks == null ? "" : item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail),
              small_image: (item.volumeInfo.imageLinks == null ? "" : item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail)


            };
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    location.assign("results.html?id=" + ui.item.id);

    },

  delay: 600,
  minLength: 2,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

$("#txtBookSearch").data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  var img = $('<image class="imageClass" src=' + item.small_image + ' alt= n/a' + '/>');
  var link = $('<a>' + item.title + ', ' + item.author + ', ' + item.publishedDate + (item.ebook == "" ? "" : ', (Ebook version)') + '</a>');
  return $('<li>')
    .append("<div>" + img.prop("outerHTML") + link.prop("outerHTML") + "</div>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
});
```

Comment: That means you don't have a `$("#txtBookSearch")` element with   `data-ui-autocomplete` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set property '\_renderItem' of undefined jQuery UI autocomplete with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513251/cannot-set-property-renderitem-of-undefined-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-html)

Comment: Please show relevant markup too with css