# data('autocomplete') is undefined in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, undefined

I have this snippet:

```
$("#select_sourcer").autocomplete(
    minLength: 2
    source: "/admin/users/list_of_sourcers.json"
    focus: (event,ui) -> 
      $('#select_sourcer').val(ui.item.full_name)
      false
    select: (event,ui) -> 
      $("#select_sourcer").val(ui.item.full_name)
      $("#merchant_sourcer_id").val(ui.item.id)
      false
    ).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = (ul, item) ->
      $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.full_name_with_status + "</a>").appendTo ul
```

And sometimes I get this error:

Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined

So I am assuming, that when:

```
$("#select_sourcer").autocomplete(...).data("autocomplete")
```

Is undefined, we can't set the attribute. As talked in this thread: [Why am I getting this JS error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590776/why-am-i-getting-this-js-error)

But, how would I do that checking of the voted answer in Coffeescript?

Comment: Why don't you set the _renderitem property directly, not per .data()?

Comment: Because it's part of the autocomplete chain? I don't understand how would you do that...

Comment: I mean, in the options object you init the autocmplete with? After inspecting some source, I think it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [accessor variant of the existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators):

> The accessor variant of the existential operator `?.` can be used to soak up null references in a chain of properties. Use it instead of the dot accessor `.` in cases where the base value may be **null** or **undefined**.

So, if you're running that jQuery and you're not certain that you have a `#select_sourcer` in the DOM, then you could just slip a `?` into the right place:

```
$("#select_sourcer").autocomplete(
  ...
  ).data("autocomplete")?._renderItem = (ul, item) ->
    #-------------------^
    ...
```

That will have more or less the same effect as:

```
x = $('#select_sourcer').autocomplete(...).data('autocomplete')
if(x)
    x._renderItem = (ul, item) -> ...
```

The above is just for illustrative purposes, `?.` actually checks `!= null` rather than general falsiness.

This should only be necessary if there is no `#select_sourcer` in the DOM so you might want to avoid attempting to bind the autocompleter altogether if you don't need it; OTOH, sometimes it is easier to not care if it is there or not and bind away.

Comment: Thank you, thank you and thank you. This has clarified a lot.