# JQueryUI 1.10.0 Autocompleter renderItem problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I tried a solution regarding renaming 'autocomplete' to 'ui-autocomplete' (using JQueryUI 1.10.0, JQuery 1.8.3) and am still getting an error for:

> TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is undefined

```
} }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
```

its defined in 1.10.0 but I need to override:

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
return $( "<li>" )
.append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.label ) )
.appendTo( ul );
},
```

here is my whole code:

```
var ajaxCall_QuickSearchCompanyId;
            $('#QuickSearchCompanyId').autocomplete({
                minLength: 2, delay: 300, source: function (request, response) {
                    if (ajaxCall_QuickSearchCompanyId) {
                        ajaxCall_QuickSearchCompanyId.abort();
                    }
                    ajaxCall_QuickSearchCompanyId = $.ajax({
                        url: '/Advertiser/Autocompleter/CompaniesDetailed', dataType: 'json',
                        data: { q: request.term },
                        success:
                            function (data) {
                                $('#QuickSearchCompanyId').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.ID,
                                        value: item.Name,
                                        subsidiaries: item.Subsidiaries,
                                        category: item.Category,
                                        url: (item.URL == null) ? '' : item.URL,
                                        parentName: item.ParentName,
                                        isReported: item.IsReported
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                    });
                }
            }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                String.prototype.chunk = function (n) {
                    var ret = []; for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i += n) { ret.push(this.substr(i, n)); }
                    return ret;
                }; ul.attr('id', 'ul_QuickSearchCompanyId'); return $('<li></li>')
                    .data('ui-autocomplete-item', item)
                    .append("<a style='padding: 0px;'><div style='margin-bottom: 0px; width: 450px;'><table style='height: 100%; width: 450px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10pt;'><tr><td style='width: 280px; border-right: solid 1px Black; padding: 0px; color: " + ((item.isReported != true) ? 'Gray' : 'Black') + "; font-style: " + ((item.isReported != true) ? 'italic' : 'none') + ";'>" + ((item.parentName != '[[root]]') ? (item.parentName + ': ') : '') + item.value + "</td><td align='right' valign='top' style='width: 150px; padding: 0px; color: " + ((item.isReported != true) ? 'Gray' : 'Black') + "; font-style: " + ((item.isReported != true) ? 'italic' : 'none') + ";'>" + item.category + "<br /></td></tr></table></div></a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
```

Any Ideas would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of

```
$('selector').data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) { };
```

you should use

```
$('selector').data('uiAutocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) { };
```

Comment: just tried this and it didn't work:

`TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]`

`}).data('uiAutocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {`

Comment: @user1214620: This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/XsskB/1. Are you sure you're using 1.10?

Comment: you saved my day ! That worked perfectly, and I just needed to add a little zIndex in my css because the autocomplete list where displaying under some elements

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. You should use `$('selector').data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {...};`

Or just open console and type something like this: `$('div').autocomplete().data()`

There you'll see the method you have to use. In my case it's just 'autocomlete'

Comment: Your suggestion to run the JS in the console was a great idea. Helped me figure my problem out.

Answer (score 5):

### I found the solution!

Well, I'll share you my little experience. When I had this same issue, I listened to people talking about change "ui-autocomplete" to "uiAutocomplete" or just "autocomplete", but that's wrong.

The correct is really "ui-autocomplete", the solution of this issue isn't this. I solve my problem when I change my code from:

```
    .data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item)
```

**to:**

```
    .__renderItem = function(ul, item)
```

Try do that and tell me what's occur.

Comment: Why downvote? This works for me and I lost my time sharing knowledge for this? Why you downvoted without give me a feedback?

Comment: Thanks!  i used *ui-autocomplete* instead of *autocomplete* This works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with this line

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
```

I was able over come the error by adding any of these

```
1 - .data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) { 
2 - .data('uiAutocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) { 
3 - .__renderItem = function(ul, item) {
```