# jQuery UI autocomplete missing _renderItem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

This is weird.

```
$.fn.autoList = function () {

return this.each(function () {

    var self = this;

    // initiate autocomplete
    $(self).autocomplete({
        source: _li_data,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.checkbox.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
            ui.item.checked = !ui.item.checked;
            $(event.target).val('');
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    if (item.checked) {
                        return $("<li>")
                                .text(item.label)
                                .addClass('preselected')
                                .appendTo(ul);
                    }
            };

});}
```

When typing and just before the results should render, I get the following error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` in jquery-ui-1.9.0.js:6672 which has the following code

```
    _renderItemData: function( ul, item ) {
    return this._renderItem( ul, item ).data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item );
},
```

What I want to do is to add a "preselected" class to a -li- item in the -ul- of the autocomplete dropdown. I am stuck with this...

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461787/jqueryui-1-10-0-autocompleter-renderitem-problems)?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately using data('uiAutocomplete') or data('ui-autocomplete') or plain data('autocomplete') doesn't help and throws the same error. Using __renderItem doesn't throw an error BUT it also doesn't do anything. 

__renderItem = function (ul, item) {
   console.log(item, 'item');
  };

doesn't log.

Comment: Well, if the if-condition `(item.checked)` is false, your `_renderItem` function will return `undefined`. Obviously you can't call any functions on that

Comment: doh!  thanks a lot. I cannot mark your answer as correct, though - because it is a comment. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_renderItem` function will return `undefined` if the `(item.checked)` condition is false. It probably just needs an `else` block:

```
// ...
._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                if (item.checked) {
                    return $("<li>")
                            .text(item.label)
                            .addClass('preselected')
                            .appendTo(ul);
                }
                // else
                return $("<li>").appendTo(ul);
        };
```